# Pinax How to add new pages?

Tags: python, django, content-management-system, pinax

How to create new pages for [Pinax](https://github.com/pinax/pinax) after installation.

Comment: For example "About" page.

Answer (score 1):

Most pages in a Django/Pinax app will be created the "normal" django way i.e. dynamically by writing views which are rendered to templates.
If you want flat pages you can either create a template e.g. about.html in your templates folder and then add 
`url(r"^about/", TemplateView.as_view(template_name="about.html"), name="about"),`
to your urls.py
Alternatively you could use the [flatpages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/flatpages/) app which lets you create flat pages from the admin system.